# How to skip empty cells while counting instances of days-of-the-week

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I've been using the following function to count the instances of days of the week in a file.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(E2:E145826)=1))
```

Now that I'm trying to count them for the entire file instead of just a small segment of it, 
the function is returning `#VALUE!`.

I think it's due to empty cells in the column. How can I modify the function to ignore these empty cells?

Comment: Weekday returns #VALUE! if there is text in the range (and it will return #NUM! if there is a number that cannot be a date, i.e. outside the range 0-2,958,465)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not a good idea to do it for the entire file but this will answer your question:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(IF(E2:E145826<>"",WEEKDAY(E2:E145826)=1)))`